# gcc can not find .o in archive

Tags: gcc

```
 mipsisa64-octeon-elf-gcc obj/zxmd_main.o obj/zxmd_mproc.o obj/zxmd_init.o obj/zxmd_pcie.o  obj/libcvm-common.a obj/libcvm-pci-drv.a  obj/libcvmhfao.a obj/libocteon-hfa.a /home/jianxi/Juson/JusonFlow/sdk/OCTEON-SDK/components/hfa/lib-octeon/pp/octeon/se/libpp.a obj/libcvmx.a obj/libzxexe.a obj/libfdt.a   -mfix-cn63xxp1 -march=octeon2 -o cn63hw1.bin
```

gcc complain:

```
obj/libzxexe.a(zxmx_tim.o): In function `zxmx_init_tim':
/home/jianxi/Juson/JusonFlow/libexec/zxmx_tim.c:47: undefined reference to `cvmx_tim_setup'
```

But `cvmx_tim_setup`  can be found in `libcvmx.a`:

```
[jianxi@jianxi obj]$ readelf -h libcvmx.a | grep "cvmx-tim.o" -A21
File: libcvmx.a(cvmx-tim.o)
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, big endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              REL (Relocatable file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          13424 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x808d4001, noreorder, octeon2, eabi64, mips64r2
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         0
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         33
  Section header string table index: 30

  [jianxi@jianxi obj]$ readelf -s cvmx-tim.o
      27: 00000000    92 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 cvmx_tim_start
      28: 00000000    40 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 cvmx_tim
      29: 00000060    56 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 cvmx_tim_stop
      30: 00000098   276 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 cvmx_tim_shutdown
      31: 000001b0   752 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 cvmx_tim_setup
      32: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND cvmx_clock_get_rate
      33: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND cvmx_bootmem_alloc
      34: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memset
      35: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND puts
      36: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf
```

When i added `cvmx-tim.o` in the command , gcc will be executed successfully：

```
mipsisa64-octeon-elf-gcc  obj/cvmx-tim.o obj/zxmd_main.o obj/zxmd_mproc.o obj/zxmd_init.o obj/zxmd_pcie.o  obj/libcvm-common.a obj/libcvm-pci-drv.a  obj/libcvmhfao.a obj/libocteon-hfa.a /home/jianxi/Juson/JusonFlow/sdk/OCTEON-SDK/components/hfa/lib-octeon/pp/octeon/se/libpp.a obj/libcvmx.a obj/libzxexe.a obj/libfdt.a -mfix-cn63xxp1 -march=octeon2 -o cn63hw1.bin
```

And if put obj/libcvmx.a in front of obj/zxmd_main.o , gcc will report more errors.

Why gcc can not find `cvmx-tim.o` in the `libcvmx.a`?

The order of `*.o` will cause problems?

Comment: +1 for detailed description of problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the order of the libraries:

```
obj/libcvmx.a obj/libzxexe.a
```

by the time the linker searches `obj/libzxexe.a` it has already processed `obj/libcvmx.a` - it won't search it again for anything that was not already been pulled in when `obj/libcvmx.a` was processed the first time around.

Change the order of those libraries to:

```
obj/libzxexe.a obj/libcvmx.a
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides changing the order of the libraries, you can also force the  cvmx_tim_setup to be a marked as 'undefined' symbol in command line. If the symbol is known to be required, then the linker will be on the lookout for it and remember the first library defining it.
add this flag to gcc command:  -Wl,--undefined=cvmx_tim_setup

Additionally you can also experiment with  --start-group and  --end-group in gcc.  --start-group (list of binaries to link) --end-group.  This will allow a full circular closure for searches.  But will cost some link performance.

Ref:
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking

Paxym